# Formatting a comment date for a REPLACE query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following code which keeps a track of a Wordpress user's most recent comment

```
    $args = array( 
        'status' => 'approve', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'number' => '1',
        'user_id' => $user_ID ); 
    $comments = get_comments($args); 

    foreach($comments as $comment) : 
        $save_comment_id = $comment->comment_ID; 
    endforeach; 

    $sql4 = 'REPLACE INTO wp_wol ( user_id, last_action_date, comment_id) VALUES ( '.$user_ID.', NOW(), '.$save_comment_id.')';
    mysql_query($sql4);
```

I have added a DATETIME field to the table called comment_date which will record the date of the user's most recent comment. So I update my code to be

```
    $args = array( 
        'status' => 'approve', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'number' => '1',
        'user_id' => $user_ID ); 
    $comments = get_comments($args); 

    foreach($comments as $comment) : 
        $save_comment_id = $comment->comment_ID; 
        $save_comment_date = $comment->comment_date;
    endforeach; 

    $sql4 = 'REPLACE INTO wp_wol ( user_id, last_action_date, comment_id, comment_date) VALUES ( '.$user_ID.', NOW(), '.$save_comment_id.', '.$save_comment_date.' )';
    mysql_query($sql4);
```

However, the comment date is not saving. I have tried the following but these changes don't seem to work so am now at a blank and need some help please.

Variations attempted based on searches

```
        $save_comment_date = strtotime($comment->comment_date);
        $save_comment_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($comment->comment_date));
        $save_comment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $comment->comment_date)));
```

but none of these seem to work. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `$comment->comment_date;` ?

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)` or

```
strtotime($datestring)
```

should work